# Namespaces in Vue js events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to have namespaces with events, like in JQuery?

like be able to do:

```
$.on('click.namespace')
$.on('change.namespace')
$.off('.namespace') // unregister both
```

Comment: The event names are just strings, so you could theoretically do it as you are setting it in the example. Unsettings however would require more work, you could probably store the events in an array or object and then loop them for the $.off call

Comment: I don't why this is necessary? This looks like an Event Bus or Vuex thing.

Comment: You need to find a third-party library that offers the feature, such as my own https://github.com/louisameline/vue-nsel (MIT)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, and usually not needed in Vue:

When using `@eventName="handler"` in the template, Vue handles the registration and de-registration of the event handlers.

And because you can specify the name of the events a components `$emit`s you won't have naming  collisions.

To  manually register & deregister an eventlistener when the component is destroyed:

```
emitter.$on(component.handleClick)
component.$on("$destroy", () => emitter.$off('click', component.handleClick))
```

Declare the handleClick in the `methods:` that creates a unique callback bound to the component.

Comment: of course it's needed. I have different modules that are hooked on the same events. And I have no way to unregister handlers for a module when it is destroyed, because $off unregisters them all. And I'm not using events inside a template btw

Comment: If you pass an unique callback to on you can deregister that specific callback if you pass that as the second parameter to call $off.